# .NET WEB API Put request is nulling out values of properties I don't include in the request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a .NET WEB API Put request that's nulling out values of properties I don't include in the request.

Here's a good request that works as expected. No surprises here:

```
PUT /api/user/id

{ 
    "nickname": "peanut", 
    "email": "cole@cole.com" 
}
```

Request in question, notice `email` isn't sent:

```
PUT /api/user/id

{ 
    "nickname": "peanut"
}
```

In the second request, if I don't send an `email` key/value, `email` gets set to `null`. Ideally, I'd leave those `email` untouched if a request like the second request is sent.

I would also like a user to be able to send a request like this, to purposefully sent a property to `null`.

```
{ 
    "nickname": "peanut", 
    "email": null 
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what your API controller action is doing because you haven't included it, however most PUT actions replace the whole object, so if you haven't included a value in the request it will get the default value, which is probably null.

Comment: Ah, right! I’ll use a PATCH instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was have the same problem with ASP.net web API. I think this is the bug in API.
If we does not set property in put method, then API assign default value to that property,
like your case `email`set with `null`.

I solved this problem by getting existed data model and then put it with changes data and send put request to update data.